# How to make a meanwell psu voltage drop?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, repair

I need to buy a 30 Volt 4 amp power supply. I used Meanwell with code number RSP-150-27 before (We set it to 30 volts with trimpot).

However, Türkiye is out of stock and there are problems with the supply process. (and expensive)

The quantity of pieces we need varies, so we do not keep them in stock.

It shows in the LRS-150-36 product datasheet that it can go down to a minimum of 32.4 volts. Can we make 30 volts by replacing the component on the product with the code LRS-150-36?

My request to you is this: Which components should we replace?

Thanks

Comment: Digikey has 543 in stock and will ship them today if needed: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/RSP-150-27/1866-4224-ND/7706288?curr=usd&utm_campaign=buynow&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_source=octopart

Answer (score 1):

**In theory**, if you replace the components of the 36V version by the ones from the 27V one (provided the PCB itself is the same), you should get the same voltage. If the PCB itself is different (possible, even if having the same PCB though the series seems a little bit more likely), then it becomes more complicated.

However, without having one unit of each at hand, or retro-engineering the 36V version, there is no way to know which components to change.

What's more, changing those components will be expensive (manual labor), and even worse, you will lose all warranty/certifications related to the original product (at least in Europe, for a commercial product, this would be a complete no go).

A safer (but still ugly) solution would be to add a linear voltage regulator to dissipate the extra 2.4V in heat, but it's still nearly 10W (at 4A), so you will need a big heat sink + fan.

So in your place, I would rather look for a replacement component from a different manufacturer rated for 30V (excepted if your product can support 32.4V safely, in which case your problem is already solved).

You might also contact Meanwell directly to ask if such modification is possible and how : it's not very likely they will respond to your request, but if they do, you will get your answer (and transfer at least some of the responsibility to them)

Comment: Thanks, I asked for help from Meanwell Turkiye but they didn't help. Sales strategy :-)

Comment: Or maybe they just don't want to take the risk of you suing them if something goes wrong with your modified product.